# Python-telegram-bot api 'update.message.date' is returning the wrong time. how do i fix this?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

im trying to retrieve the date and time of a message, and the date is correct, but the time is about 6 hours off. how can i fix this?

it is 5pm currently, but this line of code returns 23:00

> msgDate = update.message.date

edit: it is returning the minutes properly, so its close, just not sure on what to do about the hours.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though function built into python-telegram-bot uses the UTC timezone, so yes, it does return the proper date and time, just converted into UTC